# How can root password prompt be suppressed?

Tags: linux, shell, c++

I am running `service --status-all` on CentOS 7 (service ver. 1.1) and one of the init.d script is prompting for root password. It is doing so, because the init.d script calls another script, which reloads environment (env.sh) and calls the sudo command. I'd like the sudo command to fail in the context of my application. Attempting to do weird things like alias sudo='' has no effect, because environment is reset by the script. Specifically, this is riak 1.4 that's doing this.

I am writing an application that attempts to parse the status information from all the scripts, but the prompt by one of the scripts is causing considerable problems.

Is it possible to do something to suppress the sudo password prompt, without modifying the sudoers file, environment, or supplying a privileged account? I'm OK with the status command failing due to lack of permissions, but I need this to happen silently - without prompts.

Comment: Which init script is doing this?  How about sending a bug report to the developers of that application, or even sending a patch?  That's very poor practice to put that in an init script in the first place.

Comment: It is an old version of riak that has since fixed this issue (version 1.4 to be exact). However, it still occasionally resides on legacy systems where my applications must be able to run. I'd rather avoid customer tickets in general for this, and blacklisting this version of riak is a slippery slope in our code.

Comment: I see.  Using CFEngine, I would just do the research on what patch can be applied to fix that particular bug, and then write a CFEngine promise to ensure the init script is fixed if riak 1.4 is installed.  Or even just promise to upgrade riak past version 1.4, if that is a viable option.  (CFEngine gives you running service information out of the box, anyway.)  Good luck on solving it.